# Photoshop water ripple refraction (from intensity map)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects

I want to create a ripple effect. I have an existing smart object with a black/transparent "ripple" effect. I want to turn this into a refraction effect so that you don't see the black/transparent effect, but you instead see the image below it refracted and bulging, like you would see in a water ripple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want a [**displacement map**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_mapping).

Photoshop can do this, but it is set up a little bit differently than what you describe. To demonstrate, I am going to use [this source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4t7Co.jpg) paired along with [this displacement map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Clvck.png).

### Steps:

1. Save the displacement map as a **separate** .psd file
2. In a new document, set the source image as a Smart Object so that the displace will be applied as a Smart Filter.
3. <kbd>Filter → Distort → Displace...</kbd>, use the settings below, and click OK
   [image]
4. In the file selection window that pops up, choose the displacement map .psd file that we saved in step 1

### Result:

[image]
<sup>Left: Source Image / Center: Displacement map / Right: Finished product</sup>

---

*Photo credit: [mkozemchak](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37587579@N07/4599248198/in/pool-publicdomain/)*